# XML parsing in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing

I have a xml source and now i would like to present in my tableview.

Source code for xml:

```
<NewsML> 
  <Catalog Href="http://www.afp.com/dtd/AFPCatalog.xml"/> 
  <NewsEnvelope> 
    <DateAndTime>20091123T171818Z</DateAndTime> 
  </NewsEnvelope> 
  <NewsItem> 
    <Identification> 
      <NewsIdentifier> 
        <ProviderId>afp.com</ProviderId> 
        <DateId>20091123</DateId> 
        <NewsItemId>ext--english--infindo--olympics</NewsItemId> 
        <RevisionId PreviousRevision="0" Update="N">1</RevisionId> 
        <PublicIdentifier>urn:newsml:afp.com:20091123:ext--english--infindo--olympics:1</PublicIdentifier> 
      </NewsIdentifier> 
      <NameLabel></NameLabel> 
    </Identification> 
    <NewsManagement> 
      <NewsItemType FormalName="News"/> 
      <FirstCreated>20091123T171818Z</FirstCreated> 
      <ThisRevisionCreated>20091123T171818Z</ThisRevisionCreated> 
      <Status FormalName="Usable"/> 
    </NewsManagement> 
    <NewsComponent> 
      <AdministrativeMetadata> 
        <Provider> 
          <Party FormalName="AFP"/> 
        </Provider> 
      </AdministrativeMetadata> 
      <DescriptiveMetadata> 
        <Language FormalName="en"/> 
      </DescriptiveMetadata> 
      <NewsComponent> 
        <NewsLines> 
          <HeadLine>Speedskating: US coach of Norwegian team fired</HeadLine> 
        </NewsLines> 
        <NewsItemRef NewsItem="091123171708.6i0al11e.xml"/> 
      </NewsComponent> 
      <NewsComponent> 
        <NewsLines> 
          <HeadLine>Nordic skiing: World Cup relay results</HeadLine> 
        </NewsLines> 
        <NewsItemRef NewsItem="091122150812.uqxmotrc.xml"/> 
      </NewsComponent> 
      <NewsComponent> 
        <NewsLines> 
          <HeadLine>Nordic skiing: World Cup nordic skiing results</HeadLine> 
        </NewsLines> 
        <NewsItemRef NewsItem="091121165450.z40an55q.xml"/> 
      </NewsComponent> 
      <NewsComponent> 
        <NewsLines> 
          <HeadLine>Speed skating: CAS sets date for Pechstein ruling</HeadLine> 
        </NewsLines> 
        <NewsItemRef NewsItem="091119142901.jprznv03.xml"/> 
      </NewsComponent> 
    </NewsComponent> 
  </NewsItem> 
</NewsML>
```

XML link: http://data.moliscgateway.com/afpdata/afpfeeds?feedPath=topics/olympics/index.xml

Now i can show the "HeadLine" value in my root view of tableview (eg Speed skating: CAS sets date for Pechstein ruling). But when i tap on this table row will push to detail view (detail view will have another xml link) with value of . How can i do it?  Thanks.

Comment: If you want code formatting, you need to indent every line to be formatted by 4 spaces, not just the first.

Comment: Your last few sentences make no sense. With the value of what? How can you do what?

Answer (score 1):

You're really asking about quite a lot. My advice to you is to slowly go through Apple's Core Data sample projects ([example](http://developer.apple.com/cocoa/coredatatutorial/index.html)), the [Cocoa Dev Central](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php) Core Data tutorial to get down how to integrate tables and data models. Then, if you're comfortable with C, take a look at Apple's [XMLPerformance](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/XMLPerformance/index.html) sample project, which makes use of `libxml2`.